# What is the meaning of -<cloref1> in ATS?

Tags: ats

I often see a type like `(int, int) -<cloref1> bool`. What is the meaning of such a type?

Answer (score 2):

The `-<cloref1>` part of the type involves the decorated arrow notation to signify effects for the given function.

See [this ATS Wiki page](https://github.com/githwxi/ATS-Postiats/wiki/effects) for a list of available effects; `cloref1` means that the function is a persistent closure that requires the garbage collector (enabled by specifying the memory allocation functions via e.g. passing the `-DATS_MEMALLOC_LIBC` flag to the compiler) to be freed.